# Unable to run conda.exe

Tags: conda

[image]

Installation was successfull, but could not run `conda.exe`
try reinstalling multiple times, no success.

> C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.6.11-py37_0\Scripts>conda.exe failed to
>   create process.

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you see conda promt in installed. If conda installed successfully you must see that.

Comment: issue was after running conda.exe.   It displays an error "failed to create process"

Comment: Removed previous Python versions and did a fresh installation into C:\Anaconda3, but no success , still it fails with :"failed to create process"